# I cannot enable Windows Spotlight

Tags: windows, windows-10

For some reason, I cannot enable Windows Spotlight on my computer. I have Windows 10 Pro N, the same version as another computer in my house that has the Spotlight feature.

I think that the idea of Spotlight is great, is there any way of force-enabling it?

[image]

Comment: @Ramhound Sources!

Comment: Considering this [article from Microsoft](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/windows/whats-new/windows-spotlight) says the feature is available in Windows 10 Pro...

Comment: @Ramhound Funny - I have a computer with Windows 10 Pro and it can somehow access Spotlight.  Possibly a bug? Also, why would the home version have a feature that the pro version does not?

Comment: @Ramhound Here is the system information for the computer with the feature: http://puu.sh/pALP1.jpg

Comment: [Microsoft says](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/windows/manage/windows-spotlight): “Windows Spotlight is available in all desktop editions of Windows 10.”, and that’s how it is. No need to discuss that. Whether it’s available on N editions is the actual question.

Comment: @Ramhound Yeah, it obviously was updated because it contains info about *new Group Policy options* for Spotlight. It does *not* say Spotlight is new. [It isn’t](http://www.windowscentral.com/how-enable-windows-spotlight). Also, [here’s more info](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-start/windows-10-pro-no-windows-spotlight-option-in-lock/b161b698-89d5-47b6-aaf1-498edb71184d).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have windows pro N. Windows spotlight is definitely not included in 'N' versions of Windows (N versions are related to the EU ruling on media player).

It may or may not be an oversight on MS's part to not include Spotlight in the N versions. I can't find any info on it anywhere. No amount of patching, or reg keys will fix it.

Even installing this patch doesn't fix it. This will fix a few other missing bits.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/3133719

Comment: Ah, thanks for the answer. I thought it may be something to do with the N version.

Comment: It's the end of 2019... 

"Windows Spotlight" is absolutely not included in Windows 10 Pro N.

Change my mind.  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

you have an old build. As I know spotlight feature is only available since build 1607. So update your system

Comment: That’s simply not true. It’s available on 1511 as well.

Comment: @Ramhound So? That doesn’t make this statement true. I’ve been using it with Windows 10 Pro and build 1511. It’s available.

Comment: @Ramhound Windows Spotlight was introduced in Windows 10 Build 1511 and not in Build 1607. Technically, this should work in the OP's version of Windows.

Comment: I have updated to the Anniversary edition 1607, but I still see no option for Spotlight. Same computer, same hardware, activated Windows.